# XPS 15 (9560) touchpad not found after upgrade to Ubuntu-Budgie 17.10

Tags: touchpad, dell, 17.10, xps, budgie

No touch-pad is listed after running the `xinput` command in the terminal. External mouse works and touchscreen works, but touch-pad is not detected.

Any help is appreciated and any additional I can provide please let me know.

`xorg-synaptics` is not installed and `libinput` is newest version. I tried the grub `acpi=force` fix from another thread, but served only to slow my boot time.